# How to plot GPS coordinate points with unique color based on the values on third column in a GIS shapefile using python geopandas?

Tags: python, gps, shapefile, geopandas

I have a list of about 10,000 GPS coordinates. Each GPS coordinate has one value between 1 to 5 in the third column. I need to plot each point in a GIS shapefile with specific color based on the value in the third column. In other words, GPS coordinates with values equal to 1,2,3,4, and 5 in the third column should be plotted with red, green, white, black, and yellow (unique color) respectively in the GIS shapefile.

My code: [I don't get my intended figure.]

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
%matplotlib inline

Dist_shp = r'D:\shapefile.shp'
shp_f = gpd.read_file(Dist_shp)
gps_location = pd.read_csv(r'D:\plotGPS.csv')
crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip( gps_location["LONGITUDE"], gps_location["LATITUDE"])]
geometry[:3]

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (25,25))
shp_f.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.4,color="grey")
gps_location[gps_location['thirdcolumnvalue'] == 1].plot(ax=ax,markersize = 10, color ='red', marker="o", label = "Grade 1")
gps_location[gps_location['thirdcolumnvalue'] == 2].plot(ax=ax,markersize = 10, color ='green', marker="^",label = "Grade 2")
gps_location[gps_location['thirdcolumnvalue'] == 3].plot(ax=ax,markersize = 10, color ='white', marker="^",label = "Grade 3")
gps_location[gps_location['thirdcolumnvalue'] == 4].plot(ax=ax,markersize = 10, color ='black', marker="^",label = "Grade 3")
gps_location[gps_location['thirdcolumnvalue'] == 5].plot(ax=ax,markersize = 10, color ='yellow', marker="^",label = "Grade 5")

plt.legend(prop={'size':15})
```

Comment: Try delete/commenting-out the line `fig,ax = plt.subplots(..)`, and change its following line to `ax=shp_f.plot(alpha=0.4,color="grey")`.

Comment: @swatchai I found out my missing part on the code. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @swatchai I got trouble saving the plot with axes of GPS coordinates. Axes with GPS coordinates can clearly be seen in the plot, but after downloading the plot, it cannot be seen. Can you please help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the plot? You can edit and add updated information to your question, so people can understand/follow your progress. If new question arises, please post as a new question.